# Setting Binding.Path throws exception on some machines

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Consider following example

```
public class Test
{
    private static string _property = "Success";
    public static string Property
    {
        get { return _property; }
        set { _property = value; }
    }


    public void Check()
    {
        var prop = new PropertyPath(this.GetType().GetProperty("Property"));
        var binding = new Binding();
        binding.Source = typeof(Test);
        binding.Path = prop;
    }

    public static void DoTest()
    {
        new Test().Check();
    }
}
```

When I invoke `Test.DoTest()` it works fine on my machine but throws `InvalidOperationException` with message like "Cannot assign Binding.StaticSource when Binding.Source is used" (this is not exact, translated text) on some other machines. If properties are not static everything works. What may cause such behavior?

Comment: How you want to bind to a static property if you target Framework 4.0 where this isn't implemented?

Comment: @LPL Well it works on my machine where only .net 4.0 is installed. Actually I need only OneWayToSource binding.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked WPF 4 years ago...I dun remember all that but use this may work.

```
public class Test : DependencyObject
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterStringProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Property", typeof(string),
        typeof(Test), new UIPropertyMetadata("Success"));
    public string Property
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FilterStringProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FilterStringProperty, value); }
    }

    public static Test Instance { get; private set; }

    static Test()
    {

    }

    public void Check()
    {
        var prop = new PropertyPath(this.GetType().GetProperty("Property"));

        var binding = new Binding();
        binding.Source = this;
        //binding.Source = typeof(Test); //-- same thing
        binding.Path = prop;

    }

    public static void DoTest()
    {

        Instance = new Test();
        new Test().Check();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the machines you're testing on have different framework versions and you're running into incompatibilities because of this new feature in .NET 4.5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588%28v=VS.110%29.aspx#static_properties

Comment: 4.5 is an in-place upgrade of the CLR so even running a 4.0 app on a machine with 4.5 installed will run against the 4.5 CLR and can behave slightly differently. Not certain if that's your problem here but it should be the first thing you check.